# Logging to /var/log/messages stopped. How to turn it back on?

Tags: systemd, rhel7

while frantically trying to resolve a time sync issue, I somehow must have turned off some (but not all journalling). /var/log/messages ends last eventing, and journalctl -eu chronyd doesn't show any new entries althogh the service is running. This persists also through reboots. To sum up:

- A little weird: chronyd not logging anything
- Other services are logging
- Really weird and a bit scary: No change to /var/log/messages after what God knows I've been doing last night.

  ```
  $ date
  Sat May  1 09:51:07 CEST 2021
  $ ls -l /var/log/messages
   -rw-------. 1 root root 16252618 Apr 30 18:07 /var/log/messages
   $ journalctl -eu chronyd | tail -n 2
   Apr 30 18:06:35 my.host systemd[1]: Stopping NTP client/server...
   Apr 30 18:06:35 my.host systemd[1]: Stopped NTP client/server.
   $ sudo systemctl status chronyd
   ● chronyd.service - NTP client/server
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/chronyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-05-01 09:34:07 CEST; 18min ago
        Docs: man:chronyd(8)
              man:chrony.conf(5)
     Process: 804 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/chrony-helper update-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 731 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chronyd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 741 (chronyd)
       Tasks: 1
      CGroup: /system.slice/chronyd.service
              └─741 /usr/sbin/chronyd

   May 01 09:34:06 my.host systemd[1]: Starting NTP client/server...
   May 01 09:34:06 my.host chronyd[741]: chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
   May 01 09:34:06 my.host chronyd[741]: Frequency -5.091 +/- 0.244 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
   May 01 09:34:07 my.host systemd[1]: Started NTP client/server.
   May 01 09:37:21 my.host chronyd[741]: Selected source xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   $
     $ systemctl status systemd-journald
   ● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-05-01 09:34:05 CEST; 26min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
          man:journald.conf(5)
    Main PID: 512 (systemd-journal)
  Status: "Processing requests..."
   Tasks: 1
  CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-journald.service
          └─512 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
  ```

Comment: The program writing to `/var/log/messages` should be `rsyslogd`, so check there, or start with `sudo lsof /var/log/messages`. The fact that chronyd is silent doesn't have to mean anything. It's not very talkative on my server (not RHEL but Ubuntu). It should have a verbose option, though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has resolved itself. It occured during a time when I had erratic, large jumps in system time. Those are now resolved, and rsyslogd is running and logs properly. Probably rsyslogd (and other services) were upset by system time going forward and backward.